# I can't get my chart to display when declaring variables not recognized by chart js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, chart.js

I would like to show in my graph the total number of patients obtained for each month of the year 2021.
But no information is shown on the graph, rather, the graphs disappear. When executing the code and inspecting the page, it tells me that the variables labeldeMes and datosdeMes are not defined.

Could you please help me to solve this error? I don't know what I'm doing wrong

**index.php**

```
//HTML document

<?php 

$querymeses = 'SELECT Monthname(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total FROM pacientes GROUP BY mes' WHERE YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) = '2021';
$resmeses =mysqli_query($conexion,$querymeses);
$rowmeses=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resmeses);

$labelMeses="";
$datosMeses="";

while($rowmeses=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resmeses)){
  $labelMeses=$labelMeses.$rowmeses['mes'].",";
  $datosMeses=$datosMeses.$rowmeses['Total'].",";
}
$labelMeses=rtrim($labelMeses,",");
$datosMeses=rtrim($datosMeses,",");

?>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var labeldeMes=[<?php echo $labelMeses; ?>]; //Here I declare the variable labeldeMes
  var datosdeMes=[<?php echo $datosMeses; ?>]; //Here I declare the variable datosdeMes
</script>

<section class="panelControl">
    <div class="container">
        
       <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card  custom-card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-category">Pacientes</h5>
                </div>

             <!--MY CAHRT-->

            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chart-area">
                    <canvas id="chartLinePurple"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
            </section>
<?php

 include('plantillas/footer.php');

?>
```

**Table pacientes**

```
CREATE TABLE `pacientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre_documento` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `num_documento` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `telf` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `embarazo` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL
  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

INSERT INTO `pacientes` (`id`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `nombre_documento`, `num_documento`, `telf`, `sexo`, `embarazo`, `fecha_nacimiento`) VALUES
(6, 'marta', 'mangue', 'dip', 655, 222987665, 'Femenino', '', '2021-12-28'),
(7, 'Mayo', 'Esono', 'dip', 5769, 551233234, 'Masculino', '', '2021-10-25'),
(40, 'Celso', 'NUESTRA', 'dip', 4334, 4343, 'Masculino', '', '2021-11-19'),
(41, 'Nathan', 'Narby Esimi', 'dip', 1111, 654890, 'Masculino', '', '2021-12-28');
```

**charts.js**

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartLinePurple").getContext("2d");

    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 230, 0, 50);

    gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.2)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(72,72,176,0.0)');
    gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(119,52,169,0)'); //purple colors

    var data = {

      labels: labeldeMes, //THIS IS WHERE I CALLED MY VARIABLE to show me the months
      
      datasets: [{
        label: "Months",
        data: datosdeMes, //THIS IS WHERE I CALLED MY VARIABLE datosdeMes
      }]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithTooltipPurple
    });
    }
}
```

This is the **footer.php** file

```
<!--LIBRARIES USED . -->
<script src="librerias/charts/charts.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Initializing the graphics
      demo.initDashboardPageCharts();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So what does the generated HTML code look like, especially the part where you are trying to assign the values to those variables?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CBroe The graphics just don't show up.

Comment: @CBroe My HTML document does not show any errors, unless I inspect my page, from there I can see that the error is that it does not consider that I have declared the variables labeldeMes and datosdeMes

Comment: _"The graphics just don't show up"_ - that is not what I asked you about.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I did not understand you

Comment: I asked you to check what the HTML code your PHP script creates actually looks like, in that section where you are trying to create those variables.

Comment: @Community Sorry, I still don't know how to use the platform very well, I'll try to do it

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. That's why I've edited the question starting with my HTML document (index.php). After making my statement to the database, as you can see below I have declared two variables (monthlabel and monthdata) in a <script> tag to be able to call them in my JS file. I don't know if I'm answering you now!

Comment: @Community Could you please tell me how to do it exactly? I already read the link that you sent me and I don't know until now how to put it into practice

Comment: Exactly, you have shown us your PHP code. But we still don't know what the _output_ of that PHP code actually looks like, and _that_ is what I asked you to check. What does the actual HTML _that your browser received_ look like?#

Comment: @CBroe Excuse me, please if I think I understand you, are you asking me to reproduce the code? If this is the case, I don't know how to do it because I still don't know how to use the platform very well. If you could tell me exactly how to do it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just asking that you check the code via "view page source" (or similar) in your browser, so that you can see whether the PHP code produced the correct output in that part - or maybe just "nothing", or a PHP error message might have made its way into the script element.

Comment: @CBroe Hello, I think I mentioned it in my description. The error I see when inspecting the page in my browser is: "the variables labeldeMes and datosdeMes are not defined." (these are the variables that I have declared in index.php and then call in charts.js)

Comment: _"these are the variables that I have declared in index.php"_ - these are the variables you _tried_ to declare there, but it obviously did not work as intended. And therefor I asked you to check what the actual HTML & JS code your PHP script produced, looks like in that place.

Comment: @CBroe This is the error that is displayed regarding the file a charts.js  "// var labeldeMes=[<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\yaunde-main\plantillas\footer.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
Array];
  //var datosdeMes=[<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\yaunde-main\plantillas\footer.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
Array]; "

Comment: @CBroe This is what is displayed in index.php where I have declared the variables "<script> var labeldeMes=['December','November','October'];
var labeldeMes=['2','1','1']; </script> ". This means that there is no problem anymore where I declare the variables but to receive their value in charts.js

Comment: @CBroe Now my problem is knowing how to receive the values of the variables in the JS file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When needing to debug something, or developing in general, turning up the error_reporting level and making sure the errors are displayed is a good idea. Add the following two lines to the top of your index.php (or another PHP file which is included everywhere) -

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Your string assignment for `$querymeses` is invalid -

```
$querymeses = 'SELECT Monthname(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total FROM pacientes GROUP BY mes' WHERE YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) = '2021';
```

and you should be seeing an error along the lines of -

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "WHERE" in /tmp/preview on line 5
```

The WHERE clause needs to be before the GROUP BY and the query is [non-sargable](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/) due to the `YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) = 2021` criterion. I like using [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)/[nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) as I think it makes it more readable -

```
$querymeses = <<<'SQL'
    SELECT Monthname(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total
    FROM pacientes
    WHERE fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
    GROUP BY mes
    SQL;
```

You have `$rowmeses=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resmeses);` above your while loop which means you are not using the first row of your result set. And when you echo the labels into your JS the strings need to be quoted.

Putting it all together you end up with -

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$querymeses = <<<'SQL'
    SELECT Monthname(fecha_nacimiento) AS mes, count(*) AS Total
    FROM pacientes
    WHERE fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
    GROUP BY mes
    SQL;
$resmeses = mysqli_query($conexion, $querymeses);

$labelMeses = [];
$datosMeses = [];

foreach ($resmeses as $row) {
    $labelMeses[] = $row['mes'];
    $datosMeses[] = $row['Total'];
}

?>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var labeldeMes = ['<?php echo implode("','", $labelMeses); ?>']; //Here I declare the variable labeldeMes
    var datosdeMes = [<?php echo implode(',', $datosMeses); ?>]; //Here I declare the variable datosdeMes
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but my problem is still not solved!!

Comment: Thank you, I already saw the problem, it was just the quotes around the dates

Comment: Now my problem is knowing how to receive the values of the variables in the JS file!!

Comment: I was just trying to make the code less long and more readable, so I only show the part of the code where I called  my variables declared in INDEX.PHP. I need to show these values in charts.js

Comment: Everything I have in charts.js is activated after the DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked with console.log(labeldeMes, datosdeMes). Please, could you tell me how can I show all the months of the year instead of only the 3 months that I have in my database?

Comment: Hello, I am using MYSQL V.8.1.10. I would like to show the 12 months simply to know in which months there have been records in the DB and in which months there have not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MariaDB v.10.4.25. Ok, I'll try, thank you very much!